# node Async push loop

Tags: node.js, node-async

I have a async function I want to execute for i in a range. I tried this :

```
var async = require('async');

function main(a, b){

    var funcs = [];

    for(var i=a; i<=b; i++){
        var txt = "func "+i;

        funcs.push(function(callback){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(txt);
            callback(null, null);
        });
    }

    async.parallelLimit(funcs, 10, function(){
        console.log("done");
    });

}

main(1,5);
```

and the output is :

```
6
func 5
6
func 5
6
func 5
6
func 5
6
func 5
done
```

why i have not "func 6" ??? and btw I want 1 2 3 4 5 ...

Thanks

Comment: What is in 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @ThomasBormans `main(1,5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions will be executed after loop is done. So after loop `i` will be equal `6`, and `txt` will be equal `func 5`. Put content of your loop into [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to fix it:

```
for(var i=a; i<=b; i++){
    (function(i) {
        var txt = "func "+i;

        funcs.push(function(callback){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(txt);
            callback(null, null);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

**PS** In [ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) (upcoming specification of JavaScript) there are [`let` variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is about closure problem :

Try this :

```
function main(a, b){

    var funcs = [];

    for(var i=a; i<=b; i++){


        funcs.push((function(c ){
           var txt = "func "+c;
          return function ()
          {
            console.log(c);
            console.log(txt);
          }
        })(i));
    }

   for (var k=0;k<funcs.length;k++)
     {
        funcs[k]();
     }


}

main(1,5);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ruwimi/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to offer my version of the solution

```
var printText = function( txt ) {
    return function( callback ) {
        print( "text " + txt );
        callback( null, null );
    };
} );

var funcs = [];
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    funcs.push( printText( i ) );
}

async.parallelLimit( funcs, 10, function() {
    console.log("done");
} );
```